# Will installing .Net 4.5 Beta break .Net 4.0 builds from the same machine?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5

This [article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) raised some concerns about the migration path from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5 (Beta).

Will installing .Net 4.5 Beta cause problem when distributing .Net 4.0 builds from the same machine or is 4.5 properly isolated from 4.0?

Comment: That article summarises it nicely: "doing an in-place update of the runtime and then not even providing a good way to tell which version is installed is pretty whacky even by Microsoft’s standards". Not even change the version number!

Comment: It's DLL Hell all over again - you would think Msft would have learnt from past experience. We have 2 vendor apps that break under .net 4.5 . I just cant understand why they took this approach instead of making it a 5.0 release which would have zero impact on legacy / vendor systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not isolated - it basically installs on top. I wouldn't say it will necessarily break your builds - but there's no guarantee that it won't *change* your builds. In particular, I don't know of any way to get back to the "stock" v4 C# compiler.

I personally wouldn't recommend installing it directly on any machine where you really care about the builds. Go for a VM instead.

Comment: Thanks Jon. Now I just need to remember to never install some shiny new things late at night after a glass of wine :)